# Compress large JSON/JS object from content script to background.js - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects, compression

I want to send a large JSON/JS object from content.js to background.js

I have tried the library `lz-string` to compress the object.

**content.js**

```
var compressedJSON = LZString.compress(JSON.stringify(largeObject));
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "type1", result: compressedJSON}, function(response){
  // handle response
});
```

**background.js**

```
var uncompressedJSON = JSON.parse(LZString.decompress(request.result));
```

Doing so, I get `null` for `uncompressedJSON` in background.js

However, if I decompress the same string `compressedJSON` in content.js using `LZString.decompress()`, it works!

I wonder if UTF encoding has something to do with this. This library seems to work really well as I am able to compress my object by about 78%.

Suggestions for other libraries are welcome too!

Comment: 1) Unless your data exceeds 64MB there's no need to transfer a compressed string because it's 10-100500 times slower than just sending the original data, 2) since the background page is a *separate* page you need to load lz-string script there too, 3) try using compressToUTF16

Comment: @wOxxOm My object is greater than 64MB and I have successfully imported lz-string in background.js as well. It works with small simple un-nested objects but fails with larger objects.

Comment: @wOxxOm compressToUTF16 worked! Thanks for the suggestion. If you can add this as an answer, I could upvote and star!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LZString.compressToUTF16` and `LZString.decompressFromUTF16`:

> compressToUTF16 produces "valid" UTF-16 strings in the sense that all browsers can store them safely. So they can be stored in localStorage on all browsers tested (IE9-10, Firefox, Android, Chrome, Safari). Can be decompressed with decompressFromUTF16. This works by using only 15bits of storage per character. The strings produced are therefore 6.66% bigger than those produced by compress

However, it'd be still much much faster to send an uncompressed JSON.stringify result in 32MB string chunks (along with chunk number), then combine them in the background script.

Comment: Nice! You saved my day!!! :D